# Generate java classes from DSL grammar file

Tags: antlr, dsl, parser-generator, bnf, compiler-compiler

I'm looking for a way to generate a parser from a grammar file (BNF/BNF-like) that will populate an AST. However, I'm also looking to automatically generate the various AST classes in a way that is developer-readable.

Example:
For the following grammar file

```
expressions = expression+;
expression = CONST | math_expression;
math_expression = add_expression | substract_expression;
add_expression = expression PLUS expression;
substract_expression = expression MINUS expression;

CONST: ('0'..'9')+;
PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';
```

I would like to have the following Java classes generated (with example of what I expect their fields to be):

```
class Expressions {List<Expression> expression};
class Expression {String const; MathExpression mathExpression;} //only one should be filled.
class MathExpression {AddExpression addExpression; SubstractExpression substractExpression;}
class AddExpression {Expression expression1; Expression expression2;}
class SubstractExpression {Expression expression1; Expression expression2;}
```

And, in runtime, I would like the expression "1+1-2" to generate the following object graph to represent the AST:

```
Expressions(Expression(MathExpression(AddExpression(1, SubstractExpression(1, 2)))))
```

(never mind operator precedence).

I've been exploring DSL parser generators (JavaCC/ANTLR and friends) and the closest thing I could find was using ANTLR to generate a listener class with "enterExpression" and "leaveExpression" style methods. I found a somewhat similar code generated using JavaCC and jjtree using "multi" - but it's extremely awkward and difficult to use.

My grammar needs are somewhat simple - and I would like to automate the AST object graph creation as much as possible.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a lot of support for DSL construction, ANTLR and JavaCC probably aren't the way to go. They provide parsing, some support of building trees... and after that you're on your own.  But, as you've figured out, its a lot of work to design your own trees, work out the details, and you're hardly done with the DSL at that point; you still can't *use* it.

There are more complete solutions out there: JetBrains MPS,  Xtext, Spoofax, DMS.  All of them provide ways to define a DSL, convert it to an internal form ("build trees"), and provide support for code generation.  The first three have integrated IDE support and are intended for "small" DSLs; DMS does not, but handles real languages like C++ as well as DSLs.  I think the first three are open source;  DMS is commercial (I'm the party behind DMS).

Markus Voelter has just released an online book on [DSL Engineering](http://dslbook.org), available for your idea of a donation.   He goes into great detail on MPS, XText, Spoofax but none on DMS.   He tells you what you need to know and what you need to do; based on my skim of the book, it is pretty extensive.   You probably are not going to get off on "simple"; DSLs have a lot of semantic complexity and the supporting machinery is difficult.

I know the author, have huge respect for his skills in this arena, and have co-lectured at technical summer skills with him including having some nice beer.  Otherwise I have nothing to do this book.

Comment: being a beer-buddy is usually a better reference than being a co-worker :). Anyway - I thought MPS wouldn't do what I want - as far as I understand you build the DSL grammar and transformation rules and develop in MPS itself to create a whole program. My need is to have a portable parser that I can feed a string to and it'll output the AST for my semantic analysis. I then plan on doing multiple passes over it to understand what I need to do to satisfy the request. I'm not familiar with the other ones (I did glance at Xtext but it didn't seem to provide what I need).

Comment: ANTLR provides basic parsing and tree building ability; that's probably your best bet if you insist on stopping on trees.  But, see my essay, on Life After Parsing http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html